# Compare list of objects without equal defined

Tags: groovy, collections

I have a class without `equal` function defined. I need to compare two lists of this objects. There is some sample of my current solution:

```
def fromRecords = [new FooRecord(['ABC', 123L]), new FooRecord(['XYZ', 789L])]
storage.write(fromRecords)
def toRecords = storage.read()

for (int i = 0; i < outRecords.size(); i++) {
 assert outRecords[i].contents == records[i].contents
}
```

Is there more elegant groovy way to perform same comparison?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop, the `equals` method on the lists should take care of comparing order and check element-wise equality:

```
assert outRecords.contents == records.contents
```

The `==` operator will result in `outRecords.contents.equals(records.contents)` being called, which will check `List` equality (taking care of order and list content - element by element `.equals` checks).